# AngularJS $httpProvider Error

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I'm writing a web application in AngularJS with Django API endpoints. When I want to perform a JSON call to this endpoints, I want to catch possible errors (such as 404 not found error). For this, I'm using $httpProvider.

But when I run my application (using gulp), in the console, the browser says this error "Error: e is undefined"

This is my factory-code (basic code, will expand this in the future):

```
angular.module('qrWebapp').factory('errorInterceptor', function(){
  var errorInterceptor = {
        response: function() {
            console.log('hallo');
        }
  };
  return errorInterceptor;
});
```

And I initialize this in the config-area:

```
angular.module('qrWebapp', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you minifying your JavaScript?

Comment: I left some code out where I define different states with the help of $stateProvider. But I don't understand what you mean with minifying your JavaScript, sorry...

Comment: Minifying JavaScript means all the whitespace gets removed and where possible variable names are shortened (to names like 'e'). Google it.  This is a classic problem in Angular, and you need to use a different injection syntax (Google that too, sorry I'm on a phone)

Comment: Did browser show `hello` in console?

Comment: could you use angular.js instead of angular.min.js so that the we will get correct error where it is breaking

Comment: @Sunil D. I will look into that

Comment: @pankajparkar I will try that, I'm not so familiar with angular so I will need to figure that out (because I'm using gulp, bower will automatically choose what scripts and modules he uses)

Comment: @yazaki it did say hello in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a grance, I couldn't find anything wrong in your code.
However interceptor assumes to receive return value, therefore If you don't return any values as your sample code, it is possible to cause unexpected problems.

Try this code below.

```
angular.module('qrWebapp').factory('errorInterceptor', function($q){
  var errorInterceptor = {
        response: function(res) {
            console.log(res.status);
            if (res.status !== 200){
                // Normally show some error messages. One of the most simple way is calling alert function.
                console.log(res.status, res.data);
            }
            return $q.reject(res);
        }
  };
  return errorInterceptor;
});
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: It removed the error, but for the moment, when I load the page, it just shows a white screen. But the console keeps saying "hello"

Comment: is there an other way to catch the errors from a $http.get() - call? I know you can use the error-function from the $http service, but that didn't worked out for me...

Comment: I'm glad to hear the error removed. Now you've already caught the errors in response function. I edited my answer.

Comment: console only says "hello", no output from the second console.log()

Comment: please check `res.status` and don't forget reload updated javascript code.

Comment: Yeah. Now you could show some error message to user with the way you like. One of the most simple way to do it is calling `alert` function.(I added it as comment to my answer)